# PIG IF CONDITION

Tags: substring, apache-pig

I am learning PIG, and have the following statements :

```
> jan = LOAD 'hdfs:/201001hourlyx.txt USING PigStorage(',');
> feb = LOAD 'hdfs:/201002hourlyx.txt USING PigStorage(',');
> month_quad = UNION jan,feb;
> STORE month_quad INTO 'hdfs:/month_quad';
> SPLIT month_quad INTO split_jan IF (SUBSTRING(data, 4, 6) == '01');
```

I am getting the following error on the SPLIT

> **ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GRUNT - ERROR 1200 < line 5 column 67 > syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near ':'**

Does someone have a suggestion on what is the syntax error ?

Answer (score 2):

In Pig Latin, [`SPLIT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#SPLIT) cannot work with single condition. SPLIT is meant to Partition a relation into **two** or more relations.

**Syntax:**

```
SPLIT alias INTO alias IF expression, alias IF expression [, alias IF expression …];
```

Minimum two expressions are required to use SPLIT operator, whereas your statement contains only one and Pig expects for more.

Either add an additional `IF` clause to the statement or use its `FILTER` equivalent.

```
split_jan = FILTER month_quad by (SUBSTRING(data, 4, 6) == '01');
```